# Eliminate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I am writing TSQL to eliminate some data in a stored procedure.

The scenario is that there are four data points ID, Recordnumer, OrderDate,RejectDate

1. The ID can have multiple same or different order date and reject date.

I need to eliminate all the records apart from 1/01/1900 (This is not an actual rejection and a null which is substituted with this value).
However, if no rejection with 1/01/1900 then I should eliminate all records apart from the max of the reject date.

The record number is a roumber that I have done using Row over partition. Please shed a light: The image a particular records and I need to apply this rule on all the records in the table. The expected results are highlighted in yellow for different ID's

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Comment: Is a "roumber"? Should that be row-number?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have marked the expected result.

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.reject_date = '1900-01-01' or
      t.reject_date = (select max(t2.reject_date)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.id = t.id
                      );
```

For each id, this keeps the rows where the `reject_date` is 1900-01-01 or the reject date is the maximum reject date for that id.

EDIT:

This might be more appropriate:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.reject_date = (select t2.reject_date
                       from t t2
                       where t2.id = t.id
                       order by (case when t2.reject_date = '1900-01-01' then 1 else 2 end),
                                t2.reject_date desc
                      );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, That was quick. However, I need for each ID to give me a max rejectdate if there is no '1900-01-01' (this means it was never rejected) in the rejectdate column. But if that is there then the ID should only return '1900-01-01'. Above query has returned all the rows since both the conditions are met with OR for this ID.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't need `row_number()` for this

```
 select id  
            , OrderDate
            , RejectDate
            , max(case when RejectDate = '1900-01-01' then '9999-12-31' else RejectDate end) as rSum
         from tableA
         group by id, OrderDate, RejectDate
```

Comment: Hi Metal, I tried with your query but it returns three rows with the above data set. I need only one to be returned with '1900' since its there in the column else it should have given me the max date in the column

Comment: i added recrodnum=1 on the condition for null dates

Comment: @Bose, seems you don't need row_number() for this, try updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Bose, that works now. One more question how to get all those records less than this max date. As I need to delete them from the table before an insert.

Comment: please ask this on separate question, so future users will not get confused. thanks